# How can I correct the marker on google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I correct the marker (Alphabates) in the attached image because this marker given the incorrect pointer Alphabates names please see image,

[image]

I have this html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> <title>Google Maps Directions Waypoints</title>    <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">   </script>  <script type="text/javascript"> var directionDisplay;    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  var map;       function initialize() {    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({  });  var myOptions = {   zoom: 10, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, } ; map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);  directionsDisplay.setMap(map); calcRoute(); } function calcRoute() { var waypts = [];  
  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.126232,0.265945) ; 
  waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true}); 

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.593165,-0.028696) ; 
  waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true});  
  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.488874,-0.287175) ; 
  waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true});  
  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.440487,-0.155701) ;
  waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true}); 

  start  = new google.maps.LatLng(51.126232,0.265945);
  end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.593165,-0.028696);


  var request = {  origin: start,  destination: end, 
  waypoints: waypts,  optimizeWaypoints: true, 
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status)
  {  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
  {    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);  
  var route = response.routes[0]; }     });   }  
  </script> 
  </head>
  <body onLoad="initialize()"> <div id="map_canvas" style="width:70%;height:80%;"></div>  </body></html>
```

Comment: Where do you expect the markers to be?  There are three of them at the initial location (the origin, destination and 1st waypoint are the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your starting point and first waypoint are the same exact point, so it happens that the B is shown on top of the A.

```
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.126232,0.265945) ; // SAME AS START
waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true}); 

stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.593165,-0.028696) ; // SAME AS END
waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true});  
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.488874,-0.287175) ; 
waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true});  
stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.440487,-0.155701) ;
waypts.push({location:stop,  stopover:true}); 

start  = new google.maps.LatLng(51.126232,0.265945); // SAME AS FIRST WAYPOINT
end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.593165,-0.028696); // SAME AS SECOND WAYPOINT
```

Remove the first waypoint and they should start from A.

For the missing E, you have an option called *optimizeWaypoints* set to true. Quote from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions :

> optimizeWaypoints (optional) specifies that the route using the supplied waypoints may be optimized to provide the shortest possible route. If true, the Directions service will return the reordered waypoints in a waypoint_order field.

This causes the second waypoint to be re-ordered to be actually the last one before end, and as these are on top of each other, same as in the start, the latter point is only shown, and the letter E is missing from your map.